# Compiling old Microsoft Fortran for Power Station source

Tags: fortran

I have an old fortran source code. In the guide provided with the software, it is written to use Microsoft Fortran for Power Station.
I tried to compile it using gfortran, but I got many errors, mostly about a function "has no IMPLICIT type", "Unclassifiable statement" and others.
How can I compile it? Can I download or purchase Microsoft Fortran for Power Station? Or how should I modify the source code to be compatible with gfortran?

UPD:
As people suggested, I switched to intel fortran, which reduced errors significantly.
Most of errors now related to "write" statements.

One of examples:

```
        write(*,'(a65,5i5)')'Excit CrosSec fit-method is unknown for XE, 
+  iSS, LL, LU, mth=', nX, iSS, LL, LU, mth
```

Which creates many errors, like:

```
    Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(417): error #5082: Syntax error, found ''' when expecting one of: ( , <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; <IDENTIFIER> <CHAR_CON_KIND_PARAM> <CHAR_NAM_KIND_PARAM> ...
        write(*,'(a65,5i5)')'Excit CrosSec fit-method is unknown for XE,
----------------------------^
    Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(417): error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ( <IDENTIFIER> INTEGER <CHAR_CON_KIND_PARAM> <CHAR_NAM_KIND_PARAM> <CHARACTER_CONSTANT> ...
        write(*,'(a65,5i5)')'Excit CrosSec fit-method is unknown for XE,
-------------------------------------------------------------------------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(418): error #5120: Unterminated character constant
        +  iSS, LL, LU, mth=', nX, iSS, LL, LU, mth
----------------------------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(418): error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ,
        +  iSS, LL, LU, mth=', nX, iSS, LL, LU, mth
---------------------------------------------------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(417): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [EXCITCROSSECFIT]
        write(*,'(a65,5i5)')'Excit CrosSec fit-method is unknown for XE,
-----------------------------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(417): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [METHODISUNKNOWNFORXE]
        write(*,'(a65,5i5)')'Excit CrosSec fit-method is unknown for XE,
```

Another typical example is

```
real(8) X,Y, B(22), RI(15), XN(15), YN(15), D0(25), D1(25),D2(25),
 +       D3(25), D4(25), HN(25), XX(3),  HH(3), NBY2(19), Cv(21),
+       CO, UU, VV, U, Y2, Hv, DXv, V
DATA B/0.,.7093602d-7,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,
     + .0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0/, XN/10.,9.,2*8.,7.,6.,5.,4.,7*3./,
     + YN/3*.6,.5,2*.4,4*.3,1.,.9,.8,2*.7/, Hv/.201/, XX/.5246476,
     + 1.65068,.7071068/, HH/.2562121,.2588268E-1,.2820948/, NBY2/9.5,
     + 9.,8.5,8.,7.5,7.,6.5,6.,5.5,5.,4.5,4.,3.5,3.,2.5,2.,1.5,1.,.5/,
     + Cv/.7093602E-7,-.2518434E-6,.8566874E-6,-.2787638E-5,.866074E-5,
     +  -.2565551E-4,.7228775E-4,-.1933631E-3,.4899520E-3, -.001173267,
     + .2648762E-2, -.005623190, .01119601, -.02084976, .03621573,
     + -.05851412, .08770816, -.121664, .15584, -.184, .2/
```

Which produces errors:

```
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(2307): error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: %FILL <IDENTIFIER>
     +       D3(25), D4(25), HN(25), XX(3),  HH(3), NBY2(19), Cv(21),
---------------------------------------------------------------------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(2308): error #5082: Syntax error, found '+' when expecting one of: <LABEL> <END-OF-STATEMENT> ; <IDENTIFIER> TYPE MODULE ELEMENTAL IMPURE NON_RECURSIVE ...
        +       CO, UU, VV, U, Y2, Hv, DXv, V
--------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(2309): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [B]
      DATA B/0.,.7093602d-7,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0,
-----------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(2310): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [XN]
     + .0,.0,.0,.0,.0,.0/, XN/10.,9.,2*8.,7.,6.,5.,4.,7*3./,
---------------------------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(2311): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [YN]
     + YN/3*.6,.5,2*.4,4*.3,1.,.9,.8,2*.7/, Hv/.201/, XX/.5246476,
-------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(2311): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [HV]
     + YN/3*.6,.5,2*.4,4*.3,1.,.9,.8,2*.7/, Hv/.201/, XX/.5246476,
--------------------------------------------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(2311): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [XX]
     + YN/3*.6,.5,2*.4,4*.3,1.,.9,.8,2*.7/, Hv/.201/, XX/.5246476,
------------------------------------------------------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(2312): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [HH]
     + 1.65068,.7071068/, HH/.2562121,.2588268E-1,.2820948/, NBY2/9.5,
--------------------------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(2312): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [NBY2]
     + 1.65068,.7071068/, HH/.2562121,.2588268E-1,.2820948/, NBY2/9.5,
-------------------------------------------------------------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(2314): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [CV]
     + Cv/.7093602E-7,-.2518434E-6,.8566874E-6,-.2787638E-5,.866074E-5,
-------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(2308): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [CO]
        +       CO, UU, VV, U, Y2, Hv, DXv, V
----------------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(2308): error #7901: A character expression is expected as a format specifier.
        +       CO, UU, VV, U, Y2, Hv, DXv, V
--------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(2308): error #7838: A scalar default-integer variable is required in this context.
        +       CO, UU, VV, U, Y2, Hv, DXv, V
--------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(2308): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [UU]
        +       CO, UU, VV, U, Y2, Hv, DXv, V
--------------------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(2308): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [VV]
        +       CO, UU, VV, U, Y2, Hv, DXv, V
------------------------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(2308): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [U]
        +       CO, UU, VV, U, Y2, Hv, DXv, V
----------------------------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(2308): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [Y2]
        +       CO, UU, VV, U, Y2, Hv, DXv, V
-------------------------------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(2308): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [DXV]
        +       CO, UU, VV, U, Y2, Hv, DXv, V
---------------------------------------^
Users_BS_1520_Dec2023.for(2308): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [V]
        +       CO, UU, VV, U, Y2, Hv, DXv, V
--------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Intel Fortran compiler is likely the closest existing relative of the now defunct Microsoft Fortran compiler.

Comment: Could you post the compilation of one of the source file, along with the gfortran command you are using, and the full output with the error messages ?

Comment: It is really hard to say what is happening. The description is way too vague and there is no guarantee that a different compiler will actually help.

Comment: Oh the other hand if the Fortran as well written more or less any compiler should be able to cope with it to this day. But without seeing any code it is impossible to say.

Comment: The code embedded in the question looks like fixed-form source that has had the indentation disrupted.  I don't see anything that looks non-standard, so if you fix the indentation, I think any modern compiler would be able to process it as fixed form.

Comment: To fix it, the `+` symbols need to be in column 6 and the text that doesn't start with a `+` needs to be in column 7 (or larger).  Also, there aren't any comments in the code that you show, but anything that starts with a `C` is probably a comment and that needs to go in column 1.

Comment: Indeed the whole indentation looks corrupted, at least as posted... Also, what are the suffixes of the files? `*.f` or `*.f90` (or other)?

Comment: @PierU it is ".for"
I fixed the indentation and in some places joined lines to a single long line, but it creates new errors

Comment: Can you point me to some indentation guide? Should I use space or tabs?

Comment: 1) statements must be comprised between columns 7 and 72 (included); if you merged several lines, they are probably now too long. 2) continuation lines are identified by a non-blank/non-zero character in column 6. 3) comment lines are identified by a `C` in the first column. 4) columns 2-5 can contain numeric labels, used by `goto` statements

Comment: You all are right, the issue is formatting.  Thank you!